# Google maps API doesn't work in safari

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, safari

hello im hosting Google maps API on my localhost for now, and it appears fine in Chrome and the mobile phone version. (both safari and chrome iPhone versions).

My problem is Google maps doesn't show when it comes to my Mac version of Safari.  the Grey(background) shows and the cursors change to the Google maps cursor, but the map and content doesn't display. what can be the problem?

Here is a link to the map. as you can see the map displays in Chrome but not in safari.(at least not for me).

http://jsbin.com/cahicomame/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip can you help?

Answer (score 1):

there is no guarantee that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` will return a result. The user may deny the permission or the geolocation-service may not be able to locate the user.

You better  initialize the map with a default-`center` (`center` is required to display the map).

Comment: the user has to accept the geolocation otherwise the site won't work. thats what the site is about. (its given to a specific group).

Comment: But you have to accept that geolocation may fail(also when permission has been granted by the user). It will depend on the used hardware and the service which will be requested by the browser. When geolocation fails, you must know what you want to get....currently you get a blank map.

Comment: You are right sir, i think i have to create a redirect page to go back to a page where I explain that they have to accept otherwise the page won't work. 
 But for now, my issue is on Safari on the computer(Mac). have you tried it? because thats my big concern for now.

Comment: Yes I've tried, but it's a issue of the service requested by the browser, no google-maps-issue. The service requested by safari didn't return a result(this may also happen with other browsers/services, especially when geolocation will be done based on the IP-address). You still have the option to request another service on your own when geolocation fails, but IP-based geolocation never is very precise

Comment: Okay, whats your suggestion then? what should i change? would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: can you help me pleas

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution after 1 hours , it's because my website (developpement) was in http and not https :) Safari will ask your localisation.