# Google Maps API doesn't work on Safari 9

Tags: google-maps, safari

Google Maps API doesn't work in Safari 9 (seemingly all devices), however, it does work in Safari 10 (and all other relevant browsers). I have no experience with Safari. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158453/google-maps-api-doesnt-work-in-safari

Comment: I believe we took care of these things. Here is the link: https://justy24.com/simplyfood-967